# Jmeter html report include Request-Response data

Tags: ant, jmeter, build.xml

I would like to ask if you know what needs to be set to end up Jmeter html report which includes request-response data(JSON) both success/error. I tried with following setting, but did not helped:

jmeter.properties

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
```

tried to force them in ant build.xml

```
    <!-- Force suitable defaults -->
    <property name="request.threads" value="1"/>
    <property name="request.threads" value="1"/>
    <property name="request.loop" value="1"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.label" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.successful" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders" value="true"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
    <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
    <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error"value="${funcMode}"/>
enter code here
```

Thanks

Comment: could you clarify a bit ? what is the html report you're talking about ? the old ant one or the new 3.0 one ? thx

Comment: I use apache-jmeter 2.13 using jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl

Comment: in addition the request-response data is not saved in JTL as well

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and the easiest solution is adding an empty response assertion applied to all requests like:

[image: Response Assertion]

When your test ends you will see something like:

[image: Ant Report]

As a side-effect it will cause all samplers failure

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on using Assertions to conditionally set pass/fail criteria.

---

If you would like to add response data and not to fail the sampler, it is more [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) related question as you will need to amend the XSL stylesheet file in order to add an extra column

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, 

I'll try to go with XSLT change, but what bothers me is that request/response data is not stored into jtl report at all. What should I do to get that working at first